# Access into global variable by Console.Readline() in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to improve my program for Fibonacci numbers using of memoization:

```
public class MyGlobals
{
    public long TotNum { get; set; }
    public long[] MyNumbers { get; set; }

    public void GetParam() 
    {
        Console.Write("n = ");
        this.TotNum = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        this.MyNumbers = new long[this.TotNum + 1];
        // set all numbers to -1
        for (int i = 0; i < this.MyNumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            this.MyNumbers[i] = -1;
        }
    }
}

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyGlobals globVariable = new MyGlobals();

            globVariable.GetParam();
            long n = globVariable.TotNum;

            Console.WriteLine("Fib ({0}) = {1}", n, Fibonacci(n));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static long Fibonacci(long n)
        {
            MyGlobals globVariable = new MyGlobals();

            if (n <= 1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            if (globVariable.MyNumbers[n] != -1)
            {
                return globVariable.MyNumbers[n];
            }
            else
            {
                globVariable.MyNumbers[n] = Fibonacci(n - 1) + Fibonacci(n - 2);
            }
            return globVariable.MyNumbers[n];
        }
   }
```

I'm trying to do something like feed an array by -1 in MyGlobals class for further using MyNumbers array in Fibonacci static method.
Until line where I'm starting to call recursive fibonacci method it holds MyNumbers array in memory. But in Fibonacci method, when I create new instance of MyGlobals class for calling MyNumbers array is this array empty... What I'm doing wrong. Can you anybody help me on this, please. Thank you very much in forward.

Comment: There is no such thing as "global" variables in C#. Anyway you need to pass a reference one way or another. You could change the method signature to look like `static long Fibonacci(long n, MyGlobals globals)`.

Comment: You are creating too many copies of `MyGlobals`. You just want to create one and pass it into `Fibonacci`.

Comment: Yes you are creating a new instance of MyGlobals which you have not initialised.  You should instead call Fibonacci(globVariable, n); and use that instance which you have already initialised in Main.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare `globVariable` as a static member of the Program class like so:

```
class Program
{
    static MyGlobals globVariable = new MyGlobals();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        globVariable.GetParam();
        long n = globVariable.TotNum;

        Console.WriteLine("Fib ({0}) = {1}", n, Fibonacci(n));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static long Fibonacci(long n)
    {
        if (n <= 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (globVariable.MyNumbers[n] != -1)
        {
            return globVariable.MyNumbers[n];
        }
        else
        {
            globVariable.MyNumbers[n] = Fibonacci(n - 1) + Fibonacci(n - 2);
        }
        return globVariable.MyNumbers[n];
    }
}
```

Comment: Well yes and no. This does solve the immediate problem, but the code quality drops dramatically. You now cannot extract the `Fibonacci()` method into its own class, as it is now coupled to the `Program` class _and_ the `MyGlobals` instance in that class, while all the method needs is a `long` and an `long[]` parameter.

Comment: Yes, that does the trick... thanks a lot. Is there any more effective solution? To avoid an issue what CodeCaster described.

Comment: @SmithiM yes, Add MyGlobals parameter to the Fibonacci() method signature

Comment: And please, could you anybody tell me, why after creating new instance of class MyGlobals in Fibonacci method I'm loosing records in MyNumbers array defined in MyGlobals class?

Comment: Because you're creating a completely new instance of that class. Imagine you bought a car and your family gets in the car. Now you buy the exact same car again. Would you expect your family sitting in it?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as global variables in C#. The problem you're having relates to instances of nonstatic classes.

You effectively have three separate units in your code:

1. One class that asks for input, holds this input and holds an array of result variables (`MyGlobals`). This is in fact way too much for a single class and should ultimately be split up.
2. One method that calculates Fibonacci numbers and stores them into the previous class (`Fibonacci`).
3. A Program class and `Main()` method which host your console application.

Now your problem is that you don't know how to access the array of inputs stored in 1 from method 2. There are various ways to solve that, each with their own cons and pros. The most obvious one is to pass a reference.

But before that, clean up your code: give classes and methods meaningful names, and extract logic into separate classes.

Here you'll remain with three classes:

```
public class FibonacciInput
{
    public void GetParam()
    {
        // Your "MyGlobals" logic
    }
}
```

Then the calculation logic:

```
public class FibonacciCalculator
{
    public long Fibonacci(long index, long[] range)
    {
        // Your "Fibonacci()" logic
    }
}
```

And the program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FibonacciInput input = new FibonacciInput();
        FibonacciCalculator calculator = new FibonacciCalculator();

        input.GetParam();
        long n = input.TotNum;

        Console.WriteLine("Fib ({0}) = {1}", n, calculator.Fibonacci(n, input.MyNumbers));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Now your calculator doesn't know anything about your input, and the need for "global variables" goes away.

The point is that the `Fibonacci()` method needs two things: the index (the Nth Fibonacci number it should calculate) and an array to work with (which you initialized on beforehand).

So by calling `calculator.Fibonacci(n, input.MyNumbers)`, you solve all problems at once.

Comment: Thank you very much CodeCaster, this is great solution!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, may be it's not really answers your question but i'd refactor your code dividing it to logical parts where each part is only responsible for one thing :

1. UI
2. Global variables
3. Class that knows how to work with fibo sequence
4. Program (entry point)

Refactored code may look something among the lines of :

```
// Globals should be static
public static class MyGlobals
{
    public static long TotNum { get; private set; }
    public static long[] MyNumbers { get; private set; }   

    public static void SetNum(long num)
    {
        TotNum = num;
        MyNumbers = new long[TotNum + 1];
    }
}

// interacts with UI

public static class UIHelper
{
    public static long GetParam() 
    {
        Console.Write("n = ");
        var number = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        return number;
    }
}

// Knows how to calc fibo

static class Fibo 
{
    static long Calc(long[] nums, long n)
    {   
        ... calc fibonacci logic
    }        
}

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // now we can use them all
            // first lets get value from console

            var num = UIHelper.GetParam();

            // set global variables with this value
            MyGlobals.SetNum(num);

            // output result : 

            Console.WriteLine("Fib ({0}) = {1}", n, Fibo.Calc(MyGlobals.MyNumbers, MyGlobals.TotalNum));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }                
   }
```

P.S.

Whether to send global values as parameters to `Fibo.Calc()` method or to access them directly from inside of it it's up to you. I vote for first option because it makes it easier to test this method by passing mock data.